# Symfony 3.1 - Cache and images

Tags: image, symfony, caching

I'm pretty new to Symfony, so hope my question won't be too dumb, and precise enough to get help.

So, i use Symfony 3.1.10 on a site which was developped by another person, and i can't get much information on this side. Yesterday, for a little problem in my views rendering, i ran the "magical" command "cache:clear --no-warmup", which went fine. But now, i get 404 errors when trying to access some images, located in : /media/cache/resolve/avatar/uploads/product/5ab37697e4da2.jpg.
At first sight, does-it seem normal to you ? Did i do anything wrong ?
To me, seems i erased with previous command some cached files (images, here), and symfony doesn't notice it, so it won't recache them, and still try to access them by cache ?

To answer following questions :
- My liip_imagine.yml file (included in config.yml file) is very simple :

```
liip_imagine:
resolvers:
   default:
      web_path: ~

filter_sets:
    cache: ~
    avatar:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [75, 75], mode: outbound }
    thumbnail:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
    middle:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [240, 180], mode: outbound }
    normal:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [800, 600], mode: outbound }
    cover:
        quality: 75
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [1200, 300], mode: outbound }

    relative_thumbnail:
        filters:
            relative_resize: { widen: 160 }
```

- tried to run the command wthout the no-warmup, and remove the /var/cache/dev folder, and got the same result (for information, it's a production site, should i clear the /var/cache/prod folder ? And if so, is there anything to take care of to not put my site down ?)
- i totally don't know where my original files should be found. But, what's sure is that i didn't find them, searching them by name (for example here, searching 5ab37697e4da2.jpg in my whole website folder didn't return anything.
- And nothing interesting in the prod.log file.

Thx,

Olivier.

Comment: I wam-up created routes and other stuff (proxies for doctrine entities and few other things). Do you have reason why use with no-warmup? Next, from path in files it looks like you are using https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle for images I would try to access path directly and see what error I get (try to log to /var/log/dev.log)

Comment: Yes, i "might" use LiipImagineBundle, i should check this but i assume you're right on this. By the way, trying to access path directly, either by /avatar/uploads/product/5ab37697e4da2.jpg or /resolve/avatar/uploads/product/5ab37697e4da2.jpg ended in a 404 http error.

Comment: Check configuration of that bundle. There is path to files, unless storage was in cache dir it should be ok. Try as well run cache:clear without -no-warmup, try to remove var/cache/dev to see if it helps. If not hou will need to post comfiguration of that bundle

Comment: Hello M.Kebza, described what i found whith my knowledge of Symfony. Hope it helps you to help me ;)

Comment: Was out for few days, from configuration looks ok. But if you can't find images even by name on filesystem, then its possible they don't exists anymore. One last change is try to switch to dev mode and acccess  /media/cache/resolve/avatar/uploads/product/5ab37697e4da2.jpg and see what it shows, but I think it will show missing file.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is configured correctly, cached data should be regenerated automatically when needed. If you get 404, it means that this is not happening.

If you get error even when trying to access the original (non-cached) file, this is the issue: original file is missing, site was working thanks to cached images, but now they're gone, too.

If this is not the case, your best chance is to check `var/logs/prod.log` to see what's wrong when creating cached images.